# Component under cpu?

Tags: cpu

**what are these components under cpu chip?**
[image]

Comment: this looks rather unusual. Usually, you find passive components, mainly capacitors below modern CPU's base interposers; these look like dies themselves.

Comment: What type/manufacturer is the CPU?

Comment: A10 fusion in iphone 7

Comment: @MarcusMüller TSMC can do some very complex wafer assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

LDO regulators, power switches, EEPROMs, or selected space-inefficient mixed-signal circuits that don't render well in the target process.

Could also be bypass capacitors.

Comment: Voltage regulators are probably the most common but I agree with this in general.

Answer (score -1):

This looks rather unusual. Usually, you find passive components, mainly capacitors below modern CPU's base interposers; these look like dies themselves.

You'd call these "chiplets", then, but it's really an unusual thing to find them between the solder balls. I'd presume this chip is something super special-use. Maybe not actually a CPU, but an image or particle sensor or something?

Comment: Cpu chip of iphones and samsung new series phone have these.